# How to handle focus like toolbar buttons

Tags: winapi, focus

I want to create a control in WinAPI which works like some toolbar buttons do: you can click the button but it cannot be focused; the focus stays on the control that had it. How do I go about it?

Comment: Easiest solution is to call `SetFocus()` in your click handler to set focus back to where you want it.

Comment: @Roger Rowland: Thanks, I'm going to try this approach. What about more thorough solutions? I'm doing a general usage control so I'm okay with a little boilerplate coding if it keeps things right.

Comment: Well it's not easy because unless the button has focus it won't get the click, so the best you can do is to set focus somewhere else afterwards. If the button click results in, say, a dialog opening, then you can `GetFocus()` in your `OnInitDialog()` handler, but otherwise it's application-specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer because I've abandoned the task eventually, but what I found is that in fact, controls have to `SetFocus(Self)` manually and they usually do that in `WM_LMOUSEDOWN` handlers.

So to handle clicks like toolbar buttons do, it's enough to not do that.

Problem is, standard controls and common frameworks usually do this automatically deep in their internals. With frameworks such as MFC or VCL it might be possible to hack this off somehow, standard `WM_LMOUSEDOWN` handler for BUTTON control seems to do SetFocus, and it can't simply be skipped because it also does click processing.